# Easier way to iterate over generator?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6

Is there an easier way (than the one I am using) to iterate over a generator? Some sort of best practice pattern or common wrapper?

In C# I'd usually have something as simple as:

```cs
public class Program {
    private static IEnumerable<int> numbers(int max) {
        int n = 0;
        while (n < max) {
            yield return n++;
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var n in numbers(10)) {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying the same in JavaScript this is the best I could come up with:

```js
function* numbers(max) {
  var n = 0;
  while (n < max) {
    yield n++;
  }
}

var n;
var numbers = numbers(10);
while (!(n = numbers.next()).done) {
  console.log(n.value);
}
```

Though I would have expected something simple as this ...

```js
function* numbers(max) {
  let n = 0;
  while (counter < max) {
    yield n++;
  }
}

for (let n in numbers(10)) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

... which is much more readable and concise, but apparently it's not as easy as that yet? I've tried `node 0.12.7` with `--harmony` flag and also `node 4.0.0 rc1`. Is there something else I have to do to enable this feature (including the usage of `let` while I am at it) if this is even available yet?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use the `for..of` syntax for generators. This creates a loop for iterable objects.

```
function* numbers(max) {
  let n = 0;
  while (n < max) {
    yield n++;
  }
}
```

Using it:

```
for (let n of numbers(10)) {
  console.log(n); //0123456789
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: *dang* it's `for..of` not `for..in` ... damn those habits. :)

Comment: Uh, no. Please remove that paragraph about async/await. You don't need promises here.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, sorry. It's a slow Monday, I thought they were interchangeable. :)

Comment: Ah `for of` is the best. I can't understand how Airbnb afford to have a rule against it in eslint.